Significant Differences in APK Size and Performance between Cloned Flutter Project and Original
I am currently having an issue with a Flutter project that I cloned from an open-source repository. The original author of the project was able to package and publish an APK with a size of 55MB. However, after cloning the project and packaging it with Android Studio, the size of my APK doubled to approximately 120MB.
Additionally, there's a noticeable difference in performance. The 120MB APK is having significant frame drops compared to the smoothly running 55MB original version.
I haven't made any significant changes to the source code that might account for the discrepancy in both package size and performance, which leads me to wonder if there may be something I am overlooking.
Could anyone shed some light on what factors might account for the increase in APK size and decrease in performance after cloning and packaging the project? Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

I have attempted to package the project using different build flavors in an effort to replicate the original 55MB size and smooth performance. Despite my efforts, the results remained unsatisfactory - there was no reduction in size or improvement in performance.

The APK is ZIP-based, you might unpack both and compare in WinMerge or BeyondCompare or bash/du/diff for a very coarse overview of which files vary so much in size.

I agree with rsaxvc, analyzing and comparing your APK with the official one is a first step. Also check the build environment. Usually there is a debug version and a release version. Debug builds are way larger because of the additional debug data included.
